# Correct multiple condition for AddOrUpdate() in EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, insert-update

Following statement in EF 6

```
db.ReceivedMessages.AddOrUpdate(r => r.PatientId == status.PatientId && 
                                    r.DialogId == status.ConversationId, record);
```

produces exception:

> The properties expression 'r => Convert(((r.PatientId ==
>   Convert(value(ManagerDB+<>c__DisplayClass6_0).status.PatientId))
>   AndAlso (r.DialogId ==
>   value(ManagerDB+<>c__DisplayClass6_0).status.ConversationId)))'
>   is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying
>   multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With {
>   t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

Changed expression to:

```
 db.ReceivedMessages.AddOrUpdate(r => new { r.PatientId, r.DialogId }, record);
```

Got another exception:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]' and 'System.Guid'.

How to use `AddOrUpdate()` properly to update by 2 columns: if PatientId-DialogId pair exists - update record, if not - insert new one?

Comment: The second attempt with anonymous type is the intended usage. However there seem to be EF implementation bug with nullable type properties which produces the second exception, so effectively you can't use `AddOrUpdate` with nullable properties.

Comment: @IvanStoev, report a bug to them? Do You think `new { r.PatientId.Value, r.DialogId.Value }` will work as expected: if PatientId-DialogId pair exists - update record, if not - insert new one?

Comment: You could try, but most likely it will not work - they expect a property path expression representing the entity property. What about reporting a bug, you could, although currently they put almost all their efforts on EF Core - I haven't seen EF6 update for a long time :(

Comment: @IvanStoev, another way to update? LINQ?

Comment: Well, eventually the "manual" approach - `var dbRecord = db.ReceivedMessages.FirstOrDefault(...);` and then do `Add` or `Update` based on `dbRecord == null`, e.g. for *Add* something like `db.ReceivedMessages.Add(record);`, for *Update* - `db.Entry(dbRecord).CurrentValues.SetValues(record);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug should be fixed in EF 6.2.0: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/9

Workaround: install [EF beta version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.2.0-beta1) or insert-update like suggested in above comment:

```
ReceivedMessage record = db.ReceivedMessages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PatientId == status.PatientId &&
                                                                    p.DialogId == status.ConversationId);
//  Add new if not exists
bool newRecord = false;
if (record == null)
{
    record = new ReceivedMessage();
    record.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    newRecord = true;
}

// Save fields
// ...

// Save to DB
if (newRecord)  // Workaround for EF 6.1 bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44811951/630169
    db.ReceivedMessages.Add(record);
else
    db.Entry(record).CurrentValues.SetValues(record);

db.SaveChanges();
```